# Docker mediawiki docker pull mediawiki:1.31.1 downloading 1.27.5 instead

Tags: docker

I use this:
https://hub.docker.com/_/mediawiki/

I do this: `docker pull mediawiki:1.31.1`
and... Docker downloads version 1.27.5.

Tag for image is 1.31.1 bad mediawiki version is 1.27.5.

Removing all images and containers not hepling.

Command `docker inspect mediawiki:1.31.1` show:
`"MEDIAWIKI_MAJOR_VERSION=1.27",
"MEDIAWIKI_BRANCH=REL1_27",
"MEDIAWIKI_VERSION=1.27.5",`

How get version 1.31.1? It seems impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working in my case. See below

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker images | grep -i mediawiki
[root@localhost ~]# docker pull mediawiki:1.31.1
1.31.1: Pulling from library/mediawiki
f17d81b4b692: Already exists
376d99d019dc: Pull complete
80b3573727f0: Pull complete
2c492579cd1f: Pull complete
9127acfc108e: Pull complete
475593d953b6: Pull complete
52442c108349: Pull complete
34b7a8ed8171: Pull complete
57b93ed05069: Pull complete
4299e0bacf8f: Pull complete
9263f9577aad: Pull complete
5ca842beb745: Pull complete
087c6240046d: Pull complete
d31af3632f76: Pull complete
8928fd73d252: Pull complete
b089431ea3f4: Pull complete
2b4c5b4f7f57: Pull complete
1b1adac96a5c: Pull complete
b631ea5aef3e: Pull complete
acc040b08360: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:edfd44b7dcb3765e2debe008ba9b4d6f8ecb0e1ff511f58fcc71b2ba28f57246
Status: Downloaded newer image for mediawiki:1.31.1
[root@localhost ~]# docker images | grep -i mediawiki
mediawiki                                             1.31.1              8832e1c4afd5        4 days ago          654MB
[root@localhost ~]# docker --version
Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87
```

If you inspect the image you will find the version is not 1.13.1 as shown below

```
[root@localhost medaiocean]# docker inspect 8832e1c4afd5 | jq '.[].Config.Env'
[
  "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
  "PHPIZE_DEPS=autoconf \t\tdpkg-dev \t\tfile \t\tg++ \t\tgcc \t\tlibc-dev \t\tmake \t\tpkg-config \t\tre2c",
  "PHP_INI_DIR=/usr/local/etc/php",
  "APACHE_CONFDIR=/etc/apache2",
  "APACHE_ENVVARS=/etc/apache2/envvars",
  "PHP_EXTRA_BUILD_DEPS=apache2-dev",
  "PHP_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS=--with-apxs2 --disable-cgi",
  "PHP_CFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2",
  "PHP_CPPFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2",
  "PHP_LDFLAGS=-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=both -pie",
  "GPG_KEYS=1A4E8B7277C42E53DBA9C7B9BCAA30EA9C0D5763 6E4F6AB321FDC07F2C332E3AC2BF0BC433CFC8B3",
  "PHP_VERSION=7.0.32",
  "PHP_URL=https://secure.php.net/get/php-7.0.32.tar.xz/from/this/mirror",
  "PHP_ASC_URL=https://secure.php.net/get/php-7.0.32.tar.xz.asc/from/this/mirror",
  "PHP_SHA256=ff6f62afeb32c71b3b89ecbd42950ef6c5e0c329cc6e1c58ffac47e6f1f883c4",
  "PHP_MD5=",
  "MEDIAWIKI_MAJOR_VERSION=1.27",
  "MEDIAWIKI_BRANCH=REL1_27",
  "MEDIAWIKI_VERSION=1.27.5",
  "MEDIAWIKI_SHA512=2f341ed5afab24b81c315db6bcc58dd617f95231f71408c08bb2a8b974c95b7edd93d0f3c857f24058111c3228b9919a0f1c2fd2f85be940dc571e390225027a"
]
```

In that case just copy the Dockerfile from https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-docker/blob/41b4758701e47c363a49ff2ef8835be5f69cf383/1.31/Dockerfile
and build the image manually. It seems they pushed the images with the wrong tag.

```
[root@localhost medaiocean]# ls
Dockerfile
[root@localhost medaiocean]# docker build -t mediawiki:latest .

[root@localhost medaiocean]# docker images | grep -i media
mediawiki                                             latest              27ffb14d783f        3 minutes ago       687MB
mediawiki                                             1.31.1              8832e1c4afd5        4 days ago          654MB
[root@localhost medaiocean]# docker inspect 27ffb14d783f | jq '.[].Config.Env'
[
  "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
  "PHPIZE_DEPS=autoconf \t\tdpkg-dev \t\tfile \t\tg++ \t\tgcc \t\tlibc-dev \t\tmake \t\tpkg-config \t\tre2c",
  "PHP_INI_DIR=/usr/local/etc/php",
  "APACHE_CONFDIR=/etc/apache2",
  "APACHE_ENVVARS=/etc/apache2/envvars",
  "PHP_EXTRA_BUILD_DEPS=apache2-dev",
  "PHP_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS=--with-apxs2 --disable-cgi",
  "PHP_CFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2",
  "PHP_CPPFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2",
  "PHP_LDFLAGS=-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=both -pie",
  "GPG_KEYS=1729F83938DA44E27BA0F4D3DBDB397470D12172 B1B44D8F021E4E2D6021E995DC9FF8D3EE5AF27F",
  "PHP_VERSION=7.2.11",
  "PHP_URL=https://secure.php.net/get/php-7.2.11.tar.xz/from/this/mirror",
  "PHP_ASC_URL=https://secure.php.net/get/php-7.2.11.tar.xz.asc/from/this/mirror",
  "PHP_SHA256=da1a705c0bc46410e330fc6baa967666c8cd2985378fb9707c01a8e33b01d985",
  "PHP_MD5=",
  "MEDIAWIKI_MAJOR_VERSION=1.31",
  "MEDIAWIKI_BRANCH=REL1_31",
  "MEDIAWIKI_VERSION=1.31.1",
  "MEDIAWIKI_SHA512=ee49649cc37d0a7d45a7c6d90c822c2a595df290be2b5bf085affbec3318768700a458a6e5b5b7e437651400b9641424429d6d304f870c22ec63fae86ffc5152"
]
```

Comment: Check `docker inspect mediawiki:1.31.1`.  For me:
`"MEDIAWIKI_MAJOR_VERSION=1.27",
                "MEDIAWIKI_BRANCH=REL1_27",
                "MEDIAWIKI_VERSION=1.27.5",
`